# cdn.sstatic.net is blocked by company firewall

Tags: discussion, cdn

The site http://cdn.sstatic.net/ is blocked by my company firewall. When I try to access it, it shows as blocked due to category "content delivery networks"

Due to this, stackoverflow.com is only visible in text form and answers get caught up in the "I am not a human" captcha.

Changing the firewall is not an easy option.

Is there an alternate site, or mirror that can be used for the cdn. Or is there any other method to use stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could self-host the minimal required files from the CDN on a web server on your own machine, where you change your DNS entries (in your `hosts` file) to point to your local machine.

This is not an ideal solution, but it will work. It is better to just ask the company to allow the site because you need it for your work (guessing you are a programmer from your SO profile).

Steps (from the top of my head):

- Install a local web server. You can use IIS or any other web server program.
- See which files are requested by the sites you are visiting. Then create the appropriate folders in your web server and download the files from somewhere else.
- Put the domains from the above files in your `hosts` file (on Windows you can find them under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`). Put in there something like this: `127.0.0.1 cdn.sstatic.net`.
- Check if the URLs called from your SE site work.

Comment: Could you give some more information about that maybe a link or a tutorial, and the effort required to set something like this up.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje updated. This is quite some work though unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now at least there is a backup plan if the IT guys refuse to see reason.